# How to sort super product attributes configuration in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I created a configurable product and added associated products to it but the order of the super product attributes configuration is not sequential. It's shown in the below image. How do i sort them in order?. Current order is Option: 6,8,9,10,7 --How do i get it to Option: 6,7,8,9,10 order. can anyone please help me on this. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create your attribute, you can set position for it, you can find it in manage attributes section. if you have it as multiple select, you can add options and in the option you have position, the position is specifying the sort order so your position is
6:1
7:2
8:3
9:4
10:5
[image]